# Getting a 403 response when trying to run 'pod setup'

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

So I've started a new Xcode project and want to add cocoapods to it. I've successfully installed the gem but when I run

```
pod setup
```

I get the following:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Pod::Executable pull

error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

If I navigate to the address in question through my browser I can see the git repo without issue so can't figure out why it's rejecting it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was on an old version of git (1.6.x or something).

I also ran into trouble uninstalling git using the prescribed methods - I ended up needed to navigate to /usr/bin and removing git from there in order to install the latest version.

After that everything worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

Although, I answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071800/1084174) still sharing here for further audiences,

‘403’ means access forbidden. Sometimes your credentials stored in machines become stale especially if you switch between multiple github accounts. Below solution might work,

### Mac

1. Open Keychain app
2. In Keychain Access, search github.com
3. Find the "internet password" entry for github.com
4. Edit or delete the entry accordingly

### Windows

1. Goto control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials
2. Remove Github keys

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a temporary problem/glitch, have you tried again and is it working now?

Comment: hmm, weird. It works for me all the time, even the last few days (though it is slow). Something in your network/setup that times out perhaps?