# Error installing Alamofire in Mac Using Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am trying to install `Alamofire` for *iOS* app development using pod. My *podfile* looks like below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AlamoFireBackgroundTask' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire'
  # Pods for AlamoFireBackgroundTask

end
```

when I run

```
pod install
```

I get the following error message:

```
[!] Error installing Alamofire
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git /var/folders/0f/tk8t38hn0pq_81glyqfgsp6m0000gn/T/d20191105-77916-ujlfnd --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 4.9.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/0f/tk8t38hn0pq_81glyqfgsp6m0000gn/T/d20191105-77916-ujlfnd'...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you tried updating cocoapods? here it seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678386/getting-a-403-response-when-trying-to-run-pod-setup

Comment: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: @ jalone  cocoapods already isntalled

Comment: that's for updating it to the latest version, not only for installing it

Comment: after running the command:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.8.4 
but still same error

Comment: can you try put this at beginning of the Podfile
```source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'```

Comment: try that one but same error. I have also update git to its latest version but same error produced

Comment: Are you allowed to go on that URL? It seems you can't access the GitHub Repo. Firewall?

Comment: I can access https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire this url from browser and can download the repo. but git clone produced 403 error.

Comment: If you do yourself a git clone, it fails? Then the issue is not related to CocoaPods. https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/https-cloning-errors ? etc.

Answer (score 0):

‘403’ means access forbidden. Sometimes your credentials stored in machines become stale especially if you switch between multiple github accounts. Below solution might work,

### Mac

1. Open Keychain app
2. In Keychain Access, search github.com
3. Find the "internet password" entry for github.com
4. Edit or delete the entry accordingly

### Windows

1. Goto control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials
2. Remove Github keys